# BlockedException when using selfsigned applet in Chrome

Tags: applet, certificate, sign

I have an applet jar that I've signed using a key I created and stored using:

```
keytool.exe -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias myKey
```

Then I generated a certificate using:

```
keytool.exe -export -alias myKey -file myCertificate.crt
```

Finally I signed my applet jar using:

```
jarsigner.exe myJar.jar myKey
```

I assume the signing went well because I got only the following message:

```
Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
```

But when I tried to run the applet in Chrome using a simple html, my java console shows the following messages:

```
...
security: Trust in: *myJar.jar* expired: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 COT 1969
...
basic: your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running
ExitException[ 0]com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.performSecurityCheckForSandbox(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why is the certificate supposed to be expired? Or what could be the problem? Any ideas?

Note: I also added my site to Java's site list in Security tab of Java Control Panel